# Variable was unexpected at this time in a loop

Tags: scripting

I am new to Windows shell scripting. While running the following script, I am getting an error 
`"((j was unexpected at this time "`

```
$ for ((j=0;j<10;j++)); do   
$ rtg map -i sample1-100M -t hg19 -o map_sample1-$j --start-read=$
[j*10000000] --end-read=$[(j+1)*10000000]  
$ done
```

Comment: The problem is that you've written this in bash. Batch is completely different and looks nothing like this.

Comment: Your code is far away from Windows command line syntax. There are thousands of __FOR__ examples on Stack Overflow. Please visit some of them and read. Open a command prompt window, execute `for /?` or `help for` and read to get explained how to write a loop. Next run `set /?` or `help set` to get knowledge on how to calculate with environment variables as not possible with loop variable. Note. You need delayed expansion in body of __FOR__ loop.

Comment: @SomethingDark and Mofi Can you kindly tell me If its in bash then can it be run on windows platform? I have tried pasting this script in notepad and ran it through MS Prompt but it gave me the error i mentioned above. Can you please guide me step by step since i have no background of scipting. I need this script to work for my NGS data analysis. I took it from a tutorial. Thanks

Comment: No, bash can not be run in Windows without special software like Cygwin. If you're in a position where you cannot install third-party software on your computer, you will need to completely rewrite the script.

Comment: @SomethingDark I have Cygwin installed on my OS. So how to make it work now? Kindly guide step by step. Thanks

Comment: There are many very good guides online for using Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the bash script rewritten as batch script for the *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%j in (0,1,9) do (
    set /A OffsetStart=%%j * 10000000
    set /A OffsetEnd=OffsetStart + 10000000
    rtg.exe map -i sample1-100M -t hg19 -o map_sample1-%%j --start-read=!OffsetStart! --end-read=!OffsetEnd!
)
endlocal
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`